# Why elasticsearch return docs in different order with the same query?

Tags: elasticsearch

In elasticsearch 7.9, I have an Index with 1 shard and 1 replica. I use simple datetime filter to get docs between start time and end time, but I often get same result set in different order. I do not want to use Sort clause and compute scores. I just want to get results in same order.
So there is anyway to do this without using Sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be happening due to the fact, that you have 1 replica for your index, which might have some difference or different values for your timestamp field, you can use the [preference param](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-preference.html) and make sure, your search results are always returned from the same shard.

Refer [bouncy result issue blog in ES](https://www.programmersought.com/article/7356858558/) for more info.

Comment: so the replica shard will also be searched during query? I have only one primary shard for this index, and I think all result would be come from it.

Comment: @kyleqian replica shards are always used for search, replicas main objective is to improve the search performance(if a primary shard is on loaded, replica shard can serve the search), and to improve availability, if primary shard is lost, replica shard can be promoted to primary

Comment: @kyleqian let me know if you have further questions, otherwise please try the solution I advised and let me know if it solved your issue?

Comment: so the only way is to use sort clause in my query if I would like to  get results in same order every time for a multi-shard index? Is this true?